# convergence of series conditionally

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

to solve these problems is it good enough to write out a couple of the terms and see how it behaves or do i have to take the limit of the series to see what happens?

and if i do have to take the limit i can just compare them to other series or integrals that i know, right?

I think i have a general idea of how to solve these problems, just want to see if im right.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to write out the terms explicitly for the sum.  You will need to use the Alternate Test and Sum Comparison Test to work out those problems.

Comment: On this website, you are likely to get only "Key ideas" for those problem. I know that these are homework problems. When you write your solutions, please do not just write down "Key ideas" as shown in the answer. You need to write down "Full solution", meaning that every single details.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

First series: Yes and no

Use the alternate test to show the convergence of the series and since
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5n^2-3n}}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}n}$$
hence....

Second series: Yes and yes

$$\frac{|\cos (n)| n^2}{4^n+4^{-n}}\leq\frac{n^2}{4^n}=_\infty o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$